# Merging two or more sub-basins into one?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arc-hydro

I've been using Arc Hydro to analyze one of the unknown hilly regions with many watersheds. Unfortunately, Arc Hydro generates so many sub-basins that it looks really unrealistic and weird. However, I know that basins can be merged using the 'Basin processing toolbox'.

Does anyone know based on what criteria contiguous sub-basins are merged?

Comment: This page may give you some ideas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrological_code, especially the USGS section.